# Does iOS support Dual-Mode BLE?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, mfi

Does Apple allow dual mode BLE connectivity in iOS?  It seems that if BLE iOS apps could communicate to dual mode Bluetooth devices in BR/EDR mode, one wouldn't need to join the MFI program.

Comment: did you try implementing as suggested by @paulw11 ?? did it get approved by APP Store ?

Answer (score 1):

The CoreBluetooth library allows communication with a BLE peripheral using the GATT profile only.

The use of other profiles (aside from generic HFP/A2DP/AVRCP which is supported by AVFoundation and keyboards which have native HID support) requires going through the MFI program. So for example SPP.

And yes, iOS does not prevent using BLE for data communication while using an audio profile to the same device at the same time.

Comment: in the answer you mentioned headset , would that work on A2DP ? i need to develop APP which Plays song using Classic BT and transfer data using BLE , will my APP be approved by APPSTORE ?

Comment: Yes, A2DP is one of the profiles supported without requiring MFi - See https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#1-2

Comment: i'm showing List of songs in my phone and when user selects song i will play using AVPlayer  mean while im planning to send Play/Pause commands using BLE custom profile .  i searched a lot and haven't seen any APP doing this task , i thought APP store would reject my APP since it replicates default music player Functionalities .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43856270/bluetooth-speaker-playback-and-control-by-using-dual-mode-capability-in-ios-devi                                              can you please answer this question ?

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 13 you can connect to both BLE and BR/EDR with CoreBluetooth, as introduced [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/901/?time=552).