# Bluetooth Speaker Playback and control by using Dual mode capability in iOS device ? without using iAP protocol

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, external-accessory, ios-bluetooth

I have researched a lot and yet have doubts with respect Bluetooth dual mode accessory working with iOS device. help by any expert who has experience in the following case is appreciated.

**i need the feasible solution which can get the work done and App should not be rejected while uploading to app store .** 
i have stated constraints and my solution let me know if this is valid .

Existing Resource : i have a Bluetooth speaker which is MFI Certified and supports A2DP and AVRCP profiles , it supports BLE as well as BR/EDR and has 4.0 spec implemented .

**problem statement : app should play song in speaker as well as provide AVRCP controls without using iAP2 profile.**

i have thought of following solution :
1)Assume that Bluetooth speaker(EB/EDR module) is connected to iPhone in Settings , My app has UI to show list of songs present on phone . when user selects song
i will play a song using AVPlayer in My App which will inturn start playing on speaker because of A2DP . **song playback using A2DP**

2) while song is playing ,App will send play/pause/stop/forward/prev commands using custom GATT profile through BLE.  **AVRCP controls using BLE custom profile**

Bluetooth chip developer doesn't have enough time to implement iAP2 protocols, but he is ready to implement Custom BLE profiles for providing alternative to AVRCP profile.

**question 1) Solution i explained above is optimal one? and will it pass APP store review process ?**

**question 2) is there any other better solution ?**

**question 3) any example of bluetooth Speaker Apps which have this implemented these features?**

**question 4) can i use External Accessory framework API's to accomplish AVRCP controls?**
i guess Accessory should implement iAP2 profile in order to work with iOS External Accessory framework API  , **correct me if I'm wrong.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion you would be better off supporting the standard AVRCP controls as then your device will work with any app that plays music.  In theory a BLE peripheral that uses GATT to control your app is fine, but only Apple can approve apps; anything else is just a guess.

Comment: bluetooth device has AVRCP implemented , how can i implement AVRCP in my iOS app so that i can control playback within my APP ?                                 NOTE : i will be playing song within my app using AVPlayer since the device is connected in settings APP song will get diverted to Bluetooth device .

Comment: You simply need to respond to the remote control events if you are the currently active player - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567554/avaudioplayer-with-remote-control-events No need for any Bluetooth specific code

Comment: Thanks :) this would work for AVRCP  !  but what about  BLE Custom GATT profile for sharing data ? will App store approve BLE Custom GATT profiles ?

Comment: Of course.  That is what Core Bluetooth is for.

Comment: thanks , one last doubt !! so establishing both BT (BR/EDR)  and BLE connection to Bluetooth device ,and communicating through them at the same time is valid for any iOS APP ?

Comment: It should be fine as long as your peripheral chipset supports it

Comment: cool ,Thanks a lot !!